How ConvLSTM1D in keras constructed from separated Conv1D and LSTM layer?
I read this doc: https://keras.io/api/layers/recurrent_layers/conv_lstm1d/
But, can we construct the equivalent layer of ConvLSTM1D with using Conv1D and LSTM layer? Or, they are entirely separated layer.
Maybe this is what I think, I'm not sure if this is correct:
from keras.api.layers import Input, Conv1D, LSTM

# this
inputs = Input((512, 1)) #(timestep, num of channels)
conv = Conv1D(filters=8, kernel_size=3)(inputs)
lstm = LSTM(16, return_sequences=True)(conv)
another_layer = (...)(lstm)

# is equivalent with
inputs = Input((512, 1))
conv_lstm = ConvLSTM1D(???)



No, they are very different. For starters, LSTM and Conv1D work on 3D inputs, but ConvLSTM1D works on 4D inputs. The LSTM and Conv parts are applied to different axes. Also, the convolutional part is integrated into the LSTM recurrence.
